# Token sale program

Tags: spl-token, token-sale-program

I have a pre-minted spl-token I want users to buy my spl-token direct to their wallet from my website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the @solana/spl-token library. You can use the MintTo instruction.

Set up the token first, and have your MintAuthority wallet keypair available in your server. When users click the mint button on your dApp, you would create a transaction with a Solana transfer instruction to your wallet, and a MintTo instruction to mint your token to your user's wallet.

Here are a couple of related links:

https://spl.solana.com/token#creating-a-new-token-type

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#createMintToInstruction

Another option is to pre-mint your tokens. Then in your dApp, it would be a simple transfer instruction. Sol transfer from your user wallet to your own wallet, and SPL transfer from your wallet to the user wallet.